# Is there any ability to decompress gzipped string using zlib in nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gzip, zlib, compression

Good day everyone! I'm trying to adapt my code with nodeJS, but got a little issue with decompression. I'm doing a request to server with xhr, and getting a compressed data in response, but I can't decompress it into a readable object.
Here is an example of my code:

```
var xmlHttp = null;

xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open(method, url, false);

for (key in headers) {
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader(key, headers[key]);
}

xmlHttp.send(postData);
console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
zlib.gunzip(xmlHttp.responseText, function(error, result) {
    console.log(error, result);
});
```

But the "console.log(error, result);" is never called, so it seems strange to me, but I can't find out what to do.

Also, surely I read all related questions here and firstly documentation, but it gives me nothing. So I'll appreciate any help, even if it be just a marked string from documentation which maybe I missed

Comment: Could you post your node.js code? It could be that you don't return anything or don't close the response.

Comment: @AndyD - sorry, but there are no more specific code to show - everything that I use from nodeJS is just an inclusion of some modules: var XMLHttpRequest = require("./xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var http = require('http');
var zlib = require('zlib');
So my request is managed by the xmlhttprequest-module, which I found here: [https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest](https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest) and it provides me the same response as if it was a default browser's XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: ah, it looked like browser code hence my question. I would recommend you use request instead of xmlhttprequest. see here https://github.com/mikeal/request

Comment: @AndyD, thanks it looks interesting, I'll try rewriting this part using proposed module, thanks again.